# How do I change font awesome icon and button class onclick?

Tags: jquery, laravel

How do I change button class and font-awesome icon onclick? When I click on the button the class and icon should be changed and vice versa.

```html
<button type="button" id="btn_hideshow" data-id="{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_hideshow">
  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</button>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn_hideshow").click(function() {
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: "/user-hide-show/" + id,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        'id': id
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        if ($("button#btn_hideshow").hasClass() == "btn btn-primary btn-sm") {
          $("button#btn_hideshow").removeClass("btn btn-primary btn-sm").addClass("btn btn-info btn-sm")
            .append().html("<i class='fa fa-eye-slash'><i/>")
        } else {
          $("button#hideAndShow").removeClass("btn btn-info btn-sm").addClass("btn btn-primary btn-sm").append().html("<i class='fa fa-eye'><i/>")
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your AJAX call is working then the issue is in the `if` statement. `hasClass()` returns a boolean value, yet you're trying to compare that to the class string to search for. Instead the string needs to be provided as an argument to the function, eg:

```
if ($("button#btn_hideshow").hasClass("btn-primary") {
```

That being said, there's a better way to do what you require.

As the `btn` and `btn-sm` classes are always present on the element they can be removed from your logic. All you then need to do is toggle the `btn-primary` and `btn-info` classes on the `button`. Similarly the child `<i>` element can be kept instead of removed/re-added, and the `fa-eye` and `fa-eye-slash` classes can be toggled. As such, try this:

```
// outside AJAX callback:
let $button = $("#btn_hideshow");

// inside AJAX callback:
$button.toggleClass('btn-primary btn-info').find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash fa-eye')
```

Comment: I have status column in database which is by default 0 which means the user is not hidden and 1 means user is hidden. If my status is 0 I want to show fa fa-eye and if my status is 1 I want to show fa fa-eye-slash.

Comment: That's a different question than you asked above. To do that you'd just need to retrieve the state of that column in the database on the server side and update the HTML output. If you need more specific help I'd suggest starting a new question about it.

Comment: Hello, Rory McCrossan, I have updated the question can you please help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306246/how-can-i-change-button-class-and-fontawesome-icon-based-on-my-database-value-0