# How can I change button class and fontawesome icon based on my database value 0 or 1 in laravel using jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have column status in database with boolean value 0 and 1. 0 means user is shown and 1 means user is hidden.

**This is my button**

```
 <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn_show" type="button" id="btn_show" data-value="{{$user->status}}" data-id="{{$user->id}}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                                </button>
```

**My Controller**

```
 public function userhideandshow($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    if ($user->status == 0) {
        $user->status = 1;
    } else {
        $user->status = 0;
    }
    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['success']);
}
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$(function () {
        $(".btn_show").click(function () {
            let status = $(this).data('value');
            console.log(value);
            let id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/user/" + id,
                method: "POST",
                data: {'id': id, 'status': value},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(value);
                    if (value == 0) {
                        $("button.btn_show").find("i").removeClass("fa fa-eye").addClass("fa fa-eye-slash");
                    } else {
                        $("button.btn_show").find("i").removeClass("fa fa-eye-slash").addClass("fa fa-eye");
                    }
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

When I click on button I want to change its class and icon based on my database value. If value is 0, then button is primary and icon is fa fa-eye and if 1 then fa fa-eye slash and button info. Database value is changing but how do I change button based on value. Thanks in advance.

**My need is this**

```html
 @if($user->status == 0)
    <button type="button" id="btn_show" data-value="{{ $user->status }}" data-id="{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_show"><i
                    class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </button>
  @else
    <button type="button" id="btn_show" data-value="{{$user->status}}" data-id="{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn_show"><i
                    class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
        </button>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set class to current clicked button, so try this

```
$(".btn_show").click(function () {
    let this_button = $(this);
    let this_button_icon = $(this).find("i"); // Add this to have current button icon instance
    let status = $(this).data('value');
    console.log(value);
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user/" + id,
        method: "POST",
        data: {'id': id, 'status': value},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(value);
        // set class to icon
        if (value == 0) {
        this_button_icon.removeClass("fa fa-eye").addClass("fa fa-eye-slash");
        this_button.attr('data-user-id', 1);
        } else {
            this_button_icon.removeClass("fa fa-eye-slash").addClass("fa fa-eye");
            this_button.attr('data-user-id', 0);
        }
    },
});
```

EDITED: Try this

```
<button type="button" id="btn_show{{$user->id}}" data-value="{{$user->status}}" data-id="{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn_show {{$user->status ? 'btn-info' : 'btn-primary'}}"><i
                class="fa {{$user->status ? 'fa-eye-slash' : 'fa-eye'}}"></i>
    </button>
```

Comment: but this button get change again on page refresh I want button to be changed based on value 0 and 1.

Comment: Do you need icon class to be changed after reload or after ajax call?

Comment: after ajax call. If I need it after page reload then above works for me well but I don't want page to reload.

Comment: No after I reload the page my button again changes to fa fa-eye. But i want it to be fa fa-eye if my status is 0 and fa fa-eye-slash if status is 1. But the laravel if condition works but it needs page to reload which I don't want.

Comment: You don't describe your issue correctly, once you say you need change after ajax call, and then after refresh

Comment: I want it after ajax call but what happens is when I refresh the page the button again changes to fa fa-eye which is not my case. My case is button should remain fa fa-eye  if status is 0 and fa fa-eye-slash if status is 1. Please look into my laravel if condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not working, The button is changing only after I reload the page.

Comment: To be clear I want button to be changed on clicked not after page reload. Currently I have to reload the page to get my button changed.

Comment: Ok so you have to try the code for js i sent you, yours doesn't work because you change all buttons classes, but you have to use $(this)

Comment: Please send me your js then. I didn't receive your js. can you please send me.

Comment: it is above EDITED, look i've commented added and edited rows

Comment: All I can see is previous code there is no other edited code other than button.

Comment: Don't you see this line? let this_button_icon = $(this).find("i");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208147/discussion-between-ruben-danielyan-and-l0op).